# Interact between django and ejabberd for web chat app

Tags: python, django, xmpp, chat

I am working on a web project, and I have to make a web chat. My structure is more or less like this: you have a username, password, nickname and email, and you can chat with other people who are in your roster. I am using django (python) for the web back-end, and xmpp for the chat part.

I have read a lot about xmpp, and I implemented a simple chat using stanzas, with adding and removal of contacts, nicknames, etc.

What I want to ask is how to communicate with django and ejabberd, for things like registering a user (I don't want in-band registration, I only want to enable registration when the user creates an account), changing passwords, updating nicknames, etc. Mostly things that need some kind of elevated privilege to do.

I did some research before posting here, I am aware of sleekxmp, but as far as I am concerned, it is just a python library for xmpp. Also, I didn't found an API for ejabberd.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [blocking](/questions/tagged/blocking) and using something like [django-celery](/questions/tagged/django-celery) Workers to circumvent that. You *don't* want to naïvely use a sleek xmpp client in a view.

Since chat is full duplex, you probably want [WebSocket + Django python WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9489720/383793)  or [Django / Comet (Push): Least of all evils?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4310706/383793) or even "oldskool" [Long polling in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6698355/383793)

Comment: Unless explicitly told to be blocking, SleekXMPP runs connection(s) in separate threads. That is, if one don't want to setup a full-fledged Celery workers, having a process-global SleekXMPP connection (or connection pool) and using those from views for commands that can either run asynchronously or don't cause significant delays - like user registration or MUC administration - is acceptable in my opinion. Those XMPP connections quite resemble DB connections in such case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ejabberd uses internal users database, but you can setup ejabberd to manage users with [external auth script](http://www.ejabberd.im/extauth) - there are example scripts for integrating with Django app, with existing database, you can also write your own extauth script [from scratch](http://re.jabber.ru/~alexey/ejabberd/doc/dev.html#htoc9)